# Does any one know how to navigate page using shake command

Tags: android, shake

i want to navigate pages using shake command but its getting errors,So what i missed in my code.I cannot understand what is Accelerometer.Here my code.

public class ACTIVITY extends Activity  {
            /** Called when the activity is first created. */

```
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            SensorManager mSensorManager;

            ShakeEvent mSensorListener;

            mSensorListener = new ShakeEvent();
            mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
            mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener,
                mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);


            mSensorListener.setOnShakeListener(new ShakeEvent.OnShakeListener() {

              public void onShake() {
                  Intent i = new Intent(shake.this, NEWACTIVITY.class);
                  startActivity(i);
              }
            });
        }}
```

Thanx for helping.

Comment: post the logcat output (ie. the stacktraces) please.

Comment: cannot run run the application because it has errors in ShakeEvent mSensorListener;  and Intent i = new Intent(shake.this, NEWACTIVITY.class); in shake

Comment: What are the errors? Post those errors.

Answer (score 0):

You said that your activity is called "ACTIVITY". But in your onShake method you create an Intent with first argument "shake.this". That doesn't make any sense, because your OnShakeListener is **not nested** in a class called "shake" (and furthermore that first argument must be a Context object!). You need to write the following instead:

```
          public void onShake() {
              Intent i = new Intent(ACTIVITY.this, NEWACTIVITY.class);
              startActivity(i);
          }
```